# Setting AutoFlash in Windows Phone 8.1/WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently using MediaCapture in a Windows Phone 8.1 app. I have the camera working as required but changing the flash state is proving difficult.
As with the default camera app, I'm looking to have three states - Auto, Off and On. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
switch (mode)
    {
      case FlashMode.Auto:
        _captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Auto = true;
        _captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Enabled = false;
        if (_captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.AssistantLightSupported)
          _captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.AssistantLightEnabled = true;
        break;

      case FlashMode.On:
        _captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Auto = false;
        _captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Enabled = true;
        if (_captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.AssistantLightSupported)
          _captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.AssistantLightEnabled = true;
        break;

      case FlashMode.Off:
        _captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Auto = false;
        _captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Enabled = false;
        if (_captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.AssistantLightSupported)
          _captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.AssistantLightEnabled = false;
        break;
    }
```

The On and Off modes work perfectly and when the camera launches it is set to Auto. However, once you've changed the camera to on, then off and then back to Auto the flash never turns on again (I've verified it's not the lighting of the scene). Any ideas how I can reenable auto flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enabled` has precedence over `Auto`, as it operates on the entire `FlashControl`.

If you want automatic flash, you need to set `Enabled` **and** `Auto` to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for this Mike, the thing that threw me off was the when the camera launches it is in Auto mode by default, yet the values are Auto = true and Enabled = false. Your solution works great.

Comment: No problem. I think those values are provided by the driver, which means different devices may launch with different "default" configurations, so it's good practice to set your own defaults anyway.